# how to attach text file to default gmail? Getting Permission Denied for Attachment toast

Tags: android

Below is the code where I'm trying to record log and attach txt file of the log to specified gmail. It keeps giving me permission denied for attachment. Look at the images to get an idea of errors.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVd5K.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnOFs.png]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIhgk.png]

Below is permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:node="replace" />
```

Code from file to send mail intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); // this will show no apps available


intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"techsupport@someemail.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Drive Bug Report");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, createReportABugBody());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                Uri fileUri = getSleepLogFileUri();
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email via...");
    startActivityForResult(chooser,0);
```

Another function to write to file:

```
private String createReportABugBody() {
        Drive driveSDK = DriveApplication.getDrive();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("Diagnostics").append("\n");
        try{
            PackageInfo pInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
            stringBuilder.append("Version: ").append(pInfo.versionName)
                    .append("(").append(pInfo.versionCode).append(")").append("\n");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stringBuilder.append("SDK Version: ").append(driveSDK.getVersion()).append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("Device Model: Brand: ").append(Build.MANUFACTURER).append(", Model: ")
                .append(Build.MODEL).append(", Product: ").append(Build.PRODUCT).append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("Type: Android \n");
        stringBuilder.append("OS: ").append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("RM25 version: ").append(driveSDK.getRm25Version()).append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("Microphone enabled: ").append(
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                .append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append("User ID: ").append(Preferences.getPreference(Constants.KEY_STRING_USER_EMAIL, getActivity(), ""));


        stringBuilder.append("\n\n\nSTART LOGS:\n");
        try {
            File sleepLog = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), mFileName);
            //                                                                               Uri uri = getUriForFile(getContext(),FILE_PROVDER_AUTHORITY ,sleepLog);
//              intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sleepLog));
            String line;


            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

To get the file

```
private Uri getSleepLogFileUri() {
        /*
            change intent to SENDTO from SEND.
            will get "permission denied" from OS when Gmail opens.
         */
        Uri uri=null;
        try {


        File filePath = new File(DriveApplication.getApplicationInstance().getFilesDir(), "logs");
        File file = new File(filePath, mFileName);
        //File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), mFileName);
         uri= Uri.fromFile(file);////getUriForFile(getContext(), FILE_PROVDER_AUTHORITY, filelocation);//Uri.fromFile(sleepLogFile);//
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, third party apps have no access to your app's `getFilesDir()`.

Second, your app should crash on Android 7.0+ with a `FileUriExposedException`.

To resolve both problems, use `FileProvider` to serve your file, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use in `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.